# How to avoid out of range exception when erasing vector in a loop?

Tags: c++, string, vector, while-loop, erase

My apologies for the lengthy explanation.

I am working on a C++ application that loads two files into two 2D string vectors, rearranges those vectors, builds another 2D string vector, and outputs it all in a report.  The first element of the two vectors is a code that identifies the owner of the item and the item in the vector.  I pass the owner's identification to the program on start and loop through the two vectors in a nested while loop to find those that have matching first elements.  When I do, I build a third vector with components of the first two, and I then need to capture any that don't match.

I was using the syntax "vector.erase(vector.begin() + i)" to remove elements from the two original arrays when they matched.  When the loop completed, I had my new third vector, and I was left with two vectors that only had elements, which didn't match and that is what I needed.  This was working fine as I tried the various owners in the files (the program accepts one owner at a time).  Then I tried one that generated an out of range error.

I could not figure out how to do the erase inside of the loop without throwing the error (it didn't seem that swap and pop or erase-remove were feasible solutions).  I solved my problem for the program with two extra nested while loops after building my third vector in this one.

I'd like to know how to make the erase method work here (as it seems a simpler solution) or at least how to check for my out of range error (and avoid it).  There were a lot of "rows" for this particular owner; so debugging was tedious.  Before giving up and going on to the nested while solution, I determined that the second erase was throwing the error.  How can I make this work, or are my nested whiles after the fact, the best I can do?  Here is the code:

```
i = 0;
while (i < AIvector.size())
{
CHECK:
    j = 0;
    while (j < TRvector.size())
    {
        if (AIvector[i][0] == TRvector[j][0])
        {
            linevector.clear();
            // Add the necessary data from both vectors to Combo_outputvector 
            for (x = 0; x < AIvector[i].size(); x++)
            {
                linevector.push_back(AIvector[i][x]);  // add AI info
            }
            for (x = 3; x < TRvector[j].size(); x++) // Don't need the the first three elements; so start with x=3.
            {
                linevector.push_back(TRvector[j][x]); // add TR info 
            }
            Combo_outputvector.push_back(linevector); // build the combo vector

            // then erase these two current rows/elements from their respective vectors, this revises the AI and TR vectors 
            AIvector.erase(AIvector.begin() + i);
            TRvector.erase(TRvector.begin() + j);
            goto CHECK;  // jump from here because the erase will have changed the two increments
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Without using vector specific functionality except the `erase` method, you can delete the same index in each iteration while checking the size.

Comment: Your actual question is unclear. If you're asking how to avoid implementing something like this without a GOTO, it's fairly simple, refactor the code into two parts. The first part is a function that searches the arrays, using nested loop, and what not, and if a match is found the resulting indexes get `return`ed, automatically breaking out of the `while` loops; and the second part that repeatedly calls the first function, and removes the matching elements from both array if the first function found a match, then tries again; or stops if the first function didn't find a match. The End.

Comment: Shouldn't `CHECK` be outside the first `while`? What happens when you erase the last element of `AIVector` and then `goto CHECK;`? Take a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) function, and especially the erase-remove example, for a cleaner and more idiomatic way to handle such problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I think I need to read some more.  I'm an aging C programmer; so I find some C++ syntax a bit overwhelming. 
 @patatahooligan, you are right.  If I use the goto, I have CHECK in the wrong place.  I moved it above the first while and my out of range error goes away.  I take it, though, that what I did here was not optimum; so back to reading... thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As already discussed, your `goto` jumps to the wrong position. Simply moving it out of the first `while` loop should solve your problems. But can we do better?

Erasing from a vector can be done cleanly with `std::remove` and `std::erase` for cheap-to-move objects, which `vector` and `string` both are. After some thought, however, I believe this isn't the best solution for you because you need a function that does more than just check if a certain row exists in both containers and that is not easily expressed with the erase-remove idiom.

Retaining the current structure, then, we can use iterators for the loop condition. We have a lot to gain from this, because `std::vector::erase` returns an iterator to the next valid element after the erased one. Not to mention that it takes an iterator anyway. Conditionally erasing elements in a vector becomes as simple as

```
auto it = vec.begin()
while (it != vec.end()) {
    if (...) 
        it = vec.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Because we assign `erase`'s return value to `it` we don't have to worry about iterator invalidation. If we erase the last element, it returns `vec.end()` so that doesn't need special handling.

Your second loop can be removed altogether. The C++ standard defines functions for searching inside STL containers. `std::find_if` searches for a value in a container that satisfies a condition and returns an iterator to it, or `end()` if it doesn't exist. You haven't declared your types anywhere so I'm just going to assume the rows are `std::vector<std::string>>`.

```
using row_t = std::vector<std::string>;
auto AI_it = AIVector.begin();
while (AI_it != AIVector.end()) {
    // Find a row in TRVector with the same first element as *AI_it
    auto TR_it = std::find_if (TRVector.begin(), TRVector.end(), [&AI_it](const row_t& row) {
        return row[0] == (*AI_it)[0];
    });

    // If a matching row was found
    if (TR_it != TRVector.end()) {
        // Copy the line from AIVector
        auto linevector = *AI_it;

        // Do NOT do this if you don't guarantee size > 3
        assert(TR_it->size() >= 3);
        std::copy(TR_it->begin() + 3, TR_it->end(),
            std::back_inserter(linevector));

        Combo_outputvector.emplace_back(std::move(linevector));

        AI_it = AIVector.erase(AI_it);
        TRVector.erase(TR_it);
    }
    else
        ++AI_it;
}
```

As you can see, switching to iterators completely sidesteps your initial problem of figuring out how not to access invalid indices. If you don't understand the syntax of the arguments for `find_if` search for the term *lambda*. It is beyond the scope if this answer to explain what they are.

A few notable changes:

- `linevector` is now encapsulated properly. There is no reason for it to be declared outside this scope and reused.
- `linevector` simply copies the desired row from `AIVector` rather than `push_back` every element in it, as long as `Combo_outputvector` (and therefore `linevector`) contains the same type than `AIVector` and `TRVector`.
- `std::copy` is used instead of a for loop. Apart from being slightly shorter, it is also more generic, meaning you could change your container type to anything that supports random access iterators and inserting at the back, and the copy would still work.
- `linevector` is moved into `Combo_outputvector`. This can be a huge performance optimization if your vectors are large!

It is possible that you used an non-encapsulated `linevector` because you wanted to keep a copy of the last inserted row outside of the loop. That would prohibit moving it, however. For this reason it is faster and more descriptive to do it as I showed above and then simply do the following after the loop.

```
auto linevector = Combo_outputvector.back();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @patatahooligan.  FYI, `AIvector`, `TRvector`, and `Combo_outputvector` are all declared as vector<vector<string>>.  `linevector` is declared as vector<string>.  All of the data are handled as strings; while there is some numerical information; no computations are done.  `linevector` is never used later it was just a temporary vector for building the 1D data to add to `Combo_outputvector`.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand this; so I want to be sure I'm reading this correctly.  

1) Am I correct that `std::back_inserter(AIvector));` should actually be `std::back_inserter(TRvector));`?  

2) Unless the file is corrupt :-(, AIvector should always have eight elements; so linevector should always be that size after `auto linevector = *AI_it;`.  I presume then that I would need to do `linevector.begin() + 8`, correct?

Thanks!

Comment: @AlG sorry that whole line was a typo. The first two arguments are the range we want to copy from and the last argument is the destination. We want to copy into `linevector` but because `std::copy` is a generic function it doesn't know to call `push_back`. `std::back_inserter` is a helper class that does just that for each element `copy` tries to copy into it.

Comment: What I mean there is that because you want to skip the first 3 elements, which we do by `TR_it->begin() + 3`, if the row pointed to by `TR_it` has less than 3 elements, we will skip over the `end` iterator and that's undefined behavior. If your code by design guarantees that there will be at least 3 elements, but you want to be safe while debugging, use the `assert` statement I added just before the `copy`.

Comment: @AlG Sorry for multiple typos, I didn't have a chance to test this code when I first wrote it. I think it's fine now (it compiles at least).

Comment: I finally got a chance to compile this into my code, and it works fine.  Thanks again!  Unfortunately, my lowly score doesn't allow me to vote you up.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! You can still accept the answer (tick button) to show that it solves your problem.

Comment: Good to know.  I went ahead and did that.  Thanks!

Comment: Another question.  I wanted to substitute the second element of TRvector for the second element of AIvector before I started building linevector. I have a working function that checks the value of (*AI_it)[0] and returns a bool.  If it returns true, I want to perform the substitution.  I tried a direct assignment, but I keep getting "iterator not dereferencable" with `(*AI_it)[2] = (*TR_it)[2];`  How can I do that? `(*TR_it)[2]` seems to be the culprit.  Thanks.

Comment: I inserted `(*AI_it)[2] = (*TR_it)[2];` into my code and it still [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/g/fcBDg8) so that's not where your problem is. Your compiler should be telling you the exact expression and line number where the error occurs. After finding the problematic line, if you can't solve it, it's probably best to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a separate question. Comments are not an appropriate medium for this.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it might have been something with iterators that I wasn't catching.  I'll follow your advice.